# Conditional formatting: automatically refer to the next cell?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a schedule with team member names and the column headers are half hour time intervals. I want to shade the cells of hours each person does not work with gray according to their shift schedule, so that I know not to schedule that person during that hour.

I have created a separate table with each person's shift schedule, and the names appear in the same order as in the schedule.

Is there any way to conditionally format the cells at once? There has to be an easier way then what I am doing now...which is one by one clicking on each person's cell and creating the formatting formula.

I can't copy paste the formatting because the formula still refers to the previous person's shift on the other table. I need it to refer to the next row.

The formula I use for conditional formatting is:

```
='Job Functions'!$O$5>$C$9
```

Where `Job Functions` is the sheet that contains the shifts, `O5` is the shift assigned to that employee, and `C9` is the column header on the schedule (6:30am). I just clicked on the cell and created a new conditional formatting rule from the excel ribbon on top...no vba.

If there is a VBAsolution to this that'd be great! I'm fairly new to VBA

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting works like this

Let's say I have an array of numbers in `A2:E5` and a header row in `A1:E1`. I want to have my array of number be green if the value of the cell is greater than it's column header. That is to say I want to compare A2>A1, B5>B1, D4>D1, etc.  this means I want the header row comparison to be constant.

In Excel formulas you use the `$` symbol to maintain constant references. Since I want the row to stay constant but I want the column to be relative to the cell in my array of numbers my header reference will be `A$1` (column is relative, row is locked).

This is just the formula used to determine if formatting will be applied or not. If it returns `true` then the conditional formatting is applied, if it returns `false` then nothing happens.

However, where the formatting is applied is determined by the `Applies to` reference. In my example below I am applying the formula `A$1<A2` to `$A$2:$E$5`. This means that in the cell `A2` the formula `A$1<A2` is used to determine if formatting is applied, but in B3 the formula `B$1<B3` is applied. This is the same logic as if you were to have dragged the formula itself into these cells.

[image]

If instead my `Applies to` formula were `$B$2:$E$5` this means that `B2` would be colored green if `A$1<A2`, and `B3` would be colored green if `A$1<A3`.

So with all that your formula should probably be

```
='Job Functions'!O5>C$9
```

Comment: Brad, thank you so much for that thorough answer! I was able to use that information for the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop it down to fill the other cells

Comment: Hi George- yes in most cases this would work. however I need the conditional formatting formula to refer to a new cell each time. When I drag and drop, the formula still refers to the original person's shift value

Comment: @SRag The reason you are not able to drag and fill is because your formula is probably written with absolute references. Post (in the question) both your formula and the Applies To range and then we can give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Hi @Brad I updated the question, let me know if that helps